# Transfer image between SQL Server databases using UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, database, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The image has been stored in another server using `image`. I have done a query to get the image and I am now trying to put it into another table using and `update` query (also set to `image`). I am getting an error "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings."

```
<cfquery name="updateCuppms" datasource="db_PerformanceApp">
    UPDATE CUPPMS 
    SET    phoneNumber ='#GetUser.telephoneNumber#',
           email = '#GetUser.mail#'
          <cfif isdefined(#GetPic.Face#) >
             , picture = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#GetPic.Face#">
          </cfif>
    WHERE  wken = #getEmployees.wken#
 </cfquery>
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2000? If not, why are you using IMAGE (deprecated) instead of VARBINARY(MAX) (not deprecated, and much easier to work with, especially in contexts like this)>

Comment: FWIW, the cause of the original error is that you are misusing `isDefined`. IsDefined expects the **name** of a variable, ie a simple string. By using pound signs around the variable `#GetPic.Face#`, you are passing its *value* instead, which is binary. Hence the error. Now having said that .. query columns always exist. So `IsDefined` is the wrong function to use anyway. As you ultimately figured out, `IsNull()` is the way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

It was the  `<cfif isdefined(#GetPic.Face#) >` that was giving me the error so change the if statement to below and now it works.

```
<cfif not isnull(GetPic.Face)>
  ,picture = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#GetPic.Face#">
</cfif>
```

Comment: FYI - you don't need to use `#` in your if statement. I've updated your answer

Comment: Be sure to use cfqueryparam on **all** of your query parameters. Both to protect the db from sql injection and for performance.